# Sort array of arrays by array value into hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of arrays

```
[ [1,23,true], [2,33,false],[3,44,true] ]
```

I'm trying to sort the array based on the [2] value of each inner array, so the outcome would be

```
true_values: [ [1,23,true],[3,44,true] ]
false_values: [ [2,33,false] ]
```

I can select the array objects but am looking for a succinct way of sorting and outputting a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = [ [1,23,true], [2,33,false],[3,44,true] ]
```

Since `group_by` keeps the order you can sort before you group by:

```
p x.sort_by{|x|x[1]}.group_by(&:last) #=> {true=>[[1, 23, true], [3, 44, true]], false=>[[2, 33, false]]}
```

and if you do not need to keep the `true`/`false` value in the hash:

```
p  x.sort_by{|x|x[1]}.group_by(&:pop) #=> {true=>[[1, 23], [3, 44]], false=>[[2, 33]]}
```

Comment: I like both, but `group_by(&:pop)` wins the day. It even has a nice sound to it. It should be noted that the second mutates `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group it by it true or false first, then sorting that hash by the contents of the second element of the array found in v.  Lastly we call `.to_h` or to hash to get the format you outlined above.

```
[10] pry(main)> arr
=> [[1, 23, true], [2, 33, false], [3, 44, true]]
[11] pry(main)> arr.group_by { |x| x[2] }.sort_by { |_, v| v.map { |i| i[1] } }.to_h
=> {true=>[[1, 23, true], [3, 44, true]], false=>[[2, 33, false]]}
```

Comment: This answer is basically unreadable.  Read this:
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: By what measure?  This is more than idiomatic for ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
arr = [[1, 44, true], [2, 33, false], [3, 23, true]]

arr.sort_by { |*_,tf| (tf && 0) || 1 }.chunk { |*_,tf| tf }.to_h
  #=> {true=>[[1, 44, true], [3, 23, true]], false=>[[2, 33, false]]}
```

If you want ties broken by, say, `arr[i][1]`, then:

```
arr.sort_by { |_,e,tf| [(tf && 0) || 1, e] }.chunk { |*_,tf| tf }.to_h
  #=> {true=>[[3, 23, true], [1, 44, true]], false=>[[2, 33, false]]}
```

Notice that I've changed `arr` given in the question to make the second point.